# Definition of affine toric variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, toric-varieties

Sorry for my bad English.

I'm trouble  about a definition of an affine toric varieties.

I often see a definition of affine toric varieties as follow;

> An affine toric variety is an  irreducible affine variety $V$ containing a torus $T_N$ as a Zariski open  subset such that  the action on $T_N$ on itself extends to algebraic action of $T_N$ on V.

Now I confuse what is data about toric variety.
When we say $V$ is a toric variety, dose it include date about a lattice $N$, an open immersion $T_N\to V,$and an  action $T_N$ on $V$?

Or simply is toric variety  a property about an algebraic variety?

Comment: To answer your first question, yes. That's what the definition is saying.

Comment: For me at least, there is a question of what kind of “torus” is being talked about here. I would have thought that it’s an “algebraic torus”. Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_torus ,